# Collared boundary of a non-metrizable manifold

Tags: gn.general-topology, differential-topology, manifolds

For this question a manifold-with-boundary is a topological space which is Hausdorff and locally upper-Euclidean. Every metrizable manifold-with-boundary has a collared boundary, as shown in "Locally flat imbeddings of topological manifolds", Morton Brown, 1962. Let $M$ be a *non-metrizable* manifold-with-boundary. Does $M$ have a collared boundary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A nice recent reference for questions about non-metrisable manifolds is David Gauld's book aptly named "non-metrisable manifolds". For instance it is shown that any metrisable component of the boundary of a manifold (metrisable or not) is collared (Corollary 3.11 on page 44, it is an almost immediate consequence of R. Connely proof of M. Brown's result).

This is not true if the component is non-metrisable: Example 1.29 on p. 16 (which is originally due to P. Nyikos) gives a description of a manifold whose interior is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and whose boundary is the open long ray $\mathbb{L}_{+}$. This boundary component cannot be collared because there is no embedding sending $\mathbb{L}_{+}\times[0,1]$ into the manifold.

It is not clear to me whether the usual definition of `collared' is only for connected components of the boundary or if there is a global one asking for an embedding from $\partial M\times[0,1]$ into the manifold $M$. In that case a simpler counter example is the Prüfer surface (dating back to Rado), which is also detailed in D. Gauld's book in Example 1.25.

**EDIT:** Comments by the OP (and silly ones by myself) made me realize that something was a bit unclear in the statement of Theorem 3.10 in Gauld's book, from which Corollary 3.11 follows. Here are some details.

Theorem 3.10 states that if a closed subset $B$ of a Hausdorff space $X$ is locally collared and strongly paracompact, then $B$ is collared. But actually, what is needed is a bit stronger: that $B$ is strongly paracompact **in $X$**, that is, given a cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $B$ by open sets of $X$, there is another cover $\mathcal{V}$ of $B$ by open sets of $X$ such that each member of $\mathcal{V}$ is contained in a member of $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ is star-finite **in $X$**. (Star-finite means each member intersects finitely many members.) I actually asked D. Gauld about it, and he agreed that he has been a little bit careless in the statement.

This requirement is stronger, since for instance any manifold whose components are metrisable is strongly paracompact. The boundary $\partial P$ of the Prüfer surface $P$ is a discrete union of continuum many real lines and hence is strongly paracompact (in itself, so to say). But $\partial P$ is *not* strongly paracompact in $P$, and actually $\partial P$ is not collared in $P$.

A consequence of Theorem 3.10 (amended) is that if the boundary $\partial M$ of a manifold $M$ is made of (at most) countably many metrisable components, then it is collared. The proof is by using the fact that Lindelöfness is equivalent to metrisability and strong paracompactness for connected manifolds to cover $\partial M$ by countably many euclidean sets whose union yields a strongly paracompact submanifold of $M$ also having $\partial M$ as a boundary.

Comment: Nice! I've been trying to see whether connectedness is used at all in the proofs, and it seems to me that the only reason the theorem mentions components is because Gauld defines a manifold as connected. So perhaps one could obtain a collar for the whole boundary (assuming metrizable boundary). But perhaps I'm wrong; I'll take a closer look.

Comment: I think that he mentions components because the answer may depend on which ones or how many you take. For instance a manifold may have metrisable and non-metrisable boundary components. In the example of the Prüfer surface they are all metrisable, but if you take only the interior and countably many boundary components then the manifold is metrisable and the boundary (as a whole) is collared, and if you take all of them (that is, continuum many), the boundary as a whole is not collared though each boundary component, individually, is collared. I might not be very clear (cont)

Comment: (cont) but if you look at the definition of the Prüfer surface, you should see what I mean (I hope).

Comment: The trick is that the boundary of the Prüfer surface is a discrete collection of continuum many real lines, and hence as a topological space it is metrisable (points in different components may be thought to be at fixed distance $1$). So I believe that Gauld tries to avoid this difficulty by talking only about components. What is needed is the property that the boundary is strongly paracompact (see Theorem 3.10), which is equivalent to metrisability for connected manifolds but not in general.

Comment: According to [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1974.11993635?journalCode=uamm20), also by Gould, a "paracompact locally compact space is strongly paracompact". If that holds, then I think that paracompactness, strong paracompactness, and metrizablity are equivalent even for non-connected manifolds, right?

Comment: Actually, a manifold with countably many connected components is metrisable if and only it is strongly paracompact. (See Gauld's diagram on p. 31 of his book for an astonishing amount of information about these things.) Hence the proof of Cor. 3.11 shows that a manifold with a boundary made of countably many components that are metrisable has a collared boundary. This is a small generalization. I did not check but it is possible that it appears in the original paper of R. Connely.

Comment: Sorry to flood you with comments, the one just above is of course silly: a space whose components are strongly paracompact is itself strongly paracompact, so indeed strongly paracompact and metrizable are equivalent even when not connected. But then there is something strange because I am really under the impression that the Prüfer surface has a non-collared boundary, but this boundary is itself strongly paracompact. I have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Many thanks for the update! For some reason I did not get a notification of it; perhaps my MO-settings are off. Great work picking up that detail on strong paracompactness. I also wondered how a condition on the boundary could "leak" onto the interior. With the updated requirement it makes sense.

Comment: @kaba and Mathieu Baillif: that is interesting to read about Gauld's book. Can you comment on the following regarding his Theorem 3.10: do we need that the images of the local collars are star-finite? I believe his mapping $g_\alpha$ is well-defined only with some additional condition. For example, it is not well-defined if the images of the collars have non-empty common intersection.

Comment: @shuhalo Yes, that's what I tried to explain in my edit: the images of the local collars must be start finite in order for the argument to work. Time allowing, I'll add some details to my answer to clarify a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Mathieu Baillif provided an answer to the question. I'll leave here some more notes for future readers. The following strengthening of the theorem in Gauld's book "Non-metrizable manifolds" holds:

Let $X$ be a manifold-with-boundary. Then $\partial X$ is collared in $X$ and $\partial X$ is paracompact in $\partial X$ if and only if $\partial X$ is paracompact in $X$.

This is quite a nice theorem. However, it leaves open the characterization of of non-paracompact collared boundaries. I would be interested to hear if someone can complete the characterization.

The following example shows that there exists non-paracompact collared boundaries. The open long ray is a non-paracompact manifold. Therefore, its cartesian product with the interval $[0, 1]$ is a manifold-with-boundary whose boundary is non-paracompact and clearly collared.

## Some background

An $X$-collar of $X' \subset X$ is a function $h : X' \times [0, 1] \to X$, such that

- $h$ is an embedding,
- $h(x, 0) = x$, for each $x \in X'$,
- $h(X' \times [0, 1))$ is open in $X$

A subset $X' \subset X$ is $X$-collared, if there exists an $X$-collar of $X'$.

A *local collar* of $X' \subset X$ in $X$ is a pair $(U, h)$, where $U \subset X'$ is open in $X'$, and $h : \overline{U}(X') \times [0, 1] \to X$ is an embedding such that

- $h^{-1}(X') = \overline{U}(X') \times \{0\}$,
- $h(x, 0) = x$, for each $x \in \overline{U}(X')$,
- $h(U \times [0, 1))$ is open in $X$.

A subset $X' \subset X$ is *locally collared* in $X$, if for each $x \in X'$ there exists a local collar $(U, h)$ of $X'$ in $X$ such that $x \in U$.

Here are some properties of collared subsets, which I think to have proved:

- If $X' \subset X$ is $X$-collared, then $X' \times Y$ is $(X \times Y)$-collared. Applied to manifolds-with-boundary, if $X$ is a manifold-with-boundary, $Y$ is a (boundaryless) manifold, and $\partial X$ is $X$-collared, then $X \times Y$ is a manifold-with-boundary, and $\partial (X \times Y) = \partial X \times Y$ is $(X \times Y)$-collared.
- If $X'_i \subset X_i$ is $X_i$-collared for each $i \in I$, then $\sqcup X'_I$ is $\sqcup X_I$-collared, where $\sqcup$ denotes disjoint sum.
- Let $X' \subset X$, $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{P}(X')$ be an $X'$-open cover of $X'$, $V_U = \overline{U}(X') \times [0, 1]$ for each $U \in \mathcal{U}$, and $h : X' \times [0, 1] \to X$. Then $h$ is a collar of $X'$ in $X$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is $X'$-locally finite if and only if $h$ is injective, $(U, h|V_U)$ is a local collar of $X'$ in $X$ for each $U \in \mathcal{U}$, and $\{h(V_U) : U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is $X$-locally finite.

Comment: I'll add that your question got me thinking because I noticed as well that there are cases where we cannot ensure that the collar is a closed subset of the manifold in the non-metrisable case. Connelly's and Brown's definitions of collars differ on this point, as the former includes closedness while the latter does not. 
I found these subtle points interesting enough to prepare a small note (for myself mainly) on the subject summarizing what I know. I might publish it when I am done writing it if some people are interested. (Nothing in the note is really new, just compiled in one place.)

Comment: So, thanks for asking the question in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a Brown-collar (collar being the embedding function, rather than its image) which cannot be extended to a Connelly-collar? (By definition, if I've understood correctly, the image of a Brown-collar is open, and the image of a Connelly-collar is closed.) What would be an example of this? Do link the notes if you end up writing them.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens: you can have an embedding of $\partial M\times [0,1)$ which gives a neighborhood of the boundary, but none that is a closed embedding. Such an example is given by the product of the longray with $[0,1)$ with $\omega_1\times\{0\}$ removed. If you know what these spaces are, it is not difficult to check that it is the case. If not, then maybe I'll try to finish writing up these notes and make them available. Or you can check Gauld's book where the longray (and longline) are discussed in detail.

Comment: @MathieuBaillif Thanks for the example; I could only now get back to this. Can you spell out the product in more detail? The sets don't seem to match up. Say $\mathbb{L}_{\geq 0} = \omega_1 \times [0, 1)$, and $A = \omega_1 \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb{L}_{\geq 0}$. Is it $(\mathbb{L}_{\geq 0} \setminus A) \times [0, 1)$ or something else?

Comment: The above is Connelly-collared as a disjoint sum of manifolds-with-boundary homeomorphic to $(0, 1) \times [0, 1)$, so perhaps something else...

Comment: Sorry, there is some confusion in the notation, but it is my fault. $\mathbb{L}_{\ge 0}$ is indeed $\omega_1\times[0,1)$ with lexicographic order topology, but what I had in mind is $\mathbb{L}_{\ge 0}\times [0,1)$ (with product topology) with $\omega_1\times\{0\}\times\{0\}$ removed. It is usual to identify $\omega_1$ with $\omega_1\times\{0\}\subset\mathbb{L}_{\ge 0}$, hence the confusion.

Comment: Let $X_i = \omega_i \times [0, 1) \times [0, 1)$, and $X'_i = X_i \setminus (\omega_i \times \{0\} \times \{0\})$. Then your example is $X'_1$. To gain intuition, I considered $X'_0$. Let $X = [0, \infty) \times [0, 1) \approx X_0$, and $X' = [0, \infty) \times [0, 1) \setminus (\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}) \approx X'_0$. Since $X$ and $X'$ are paracompact manifolds-with-boundaries, they both have a Connelly-collared boundary...

Comment: ... Since paracompactness does not hold when $i > 0$, I'll try to provide an explicit construction for a boundary-collar instead. We have that $\partial X' = \{0\} \times (0, 1) \cup \bigcup \{(n, n + 1) \times \{0\} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Let $h : \partial X' \times [0, 1]$ be such that $h((x, 0), t) = (x, 1/2 - |(x \mod 1) - 1/2| * t)$ and $h((0, y), t) = (1/4 - |y - 1/2| * t / 2, y)$. I think I can show that this is a Connelly-collar of $\partial X'$. But if so, I think I can extend this construction to show that $X'_i$ is also Connelly-collared. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Made some typos. $h((x, 0), t) = (x, (1/2 - |(x \mod 1) - 1/2|) * t)$ and $h((0, y), t) = ((1/4 - |y - 1/2|/2)*t, y)$.

Comment: Your example for $X_0$ is right, but you cannot do the same thing with $X_1$, as the collar is not closed. In your construction, there are points in the closure of the collar in the line  $\{\omega\}\times\{0\}\times[0,1)$. 
I have more or less finished a first (draft) version of my notes on the problem (I decided to turn them into something that might be published one day, hence with all the features of an official paper, so to say, but it is still not polished at all). Just email me if you are interested.

Comment: I'd email you, but my google-fu wasn't strong enough at finding your email address.

Comment: Do you mean that $\partial X'_i$ is not closed when $i > 0$? I'm not sure which points you are referring to. At the latest bullet point I added a theorem which I think to have proved, which provides a more general relation between local collars and a collar. I think it applies to my triangle-construction. Each triangle provides a local Connelly-collar, and the collection of those triangles is $X$-locally finite. The constructed function is also injective. By this theorem $\partial X'_i$ should be Connelly-collared for $i > 0$ too. Probably I'm missing something.

Comment: My email is mathieu.baillif at hesge.ch, it will be better to continue there than to flood this thread with comments, I think.